# Determine the eigenvalue of a real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I think to this question for two days :

Let $A$ be a $3\times3$ real matrix such that $\det(A) = 1$ and $A^{-1}= A^T$. Prove that  one of the eigenvalues is equal to $1$.

I used the fact that determinant of $A$ is the product of its eigenvalues and then I wrote many equations that I couldn't  solve the question.

Comment: Pedantic matter of taste: I always prefer the transpose to be denoted by a lower case $t$, as OP originally had it.

Comment: @User8128: My apologies for changing it. I changed it without much thought because in browser $A^t$ looks almost identical to $A'$.

Comment: @MårtenW Totally fine! As I said, I was merely being pedantic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ be an eigenvalue with eigenvector $0 \neq x \in \mathbb C^n$. Then $$(x,x) = (A^tAx,x) = (Ax,Ax) = \lvert\lambda \rvert^2 (x,x).$$ Thus $\lvert \lambda \rvert = 1$ for all eigenvalues. Since $A$ is real, eigenvalues come in conjugate pairs, so either all three are real, or two are complex and one is real, but the two which are complex form a conjugate pair. Together with $\det A = 1$, do you see why this implies that one of the eigenvalues is $1$?

Comment: det$A=1$ does not imply necessarily that $1$ is eigenvalue.

Comment: Of course not, but orthogonality + $\det A=1$ does. This is exactly what the question is asking us to prove.

Comment: I mean orthogonality and det$A=1$ does not imply it. I give a counterexample below.

Comment: The eigenvalues in the second case are $-1$, $-1$ and $1$ if I'm not mistaken. Isn't the characteristic poynomial $p(\lambda) = -(\lambda -1)(\lambda+1)^2$.

Comment: In the second case you have $1$ as eigenvalue iff $\theta=k\pi$. In other cases the _only_ eigenvalue is $-1$.

Comment: No. The characteristic polynomial is $$(-1-\lambda)((-\cos(\theta)-\lambda)(\cos(\theta)-\lambda) - \sin^2(\theta))) = (-1-\lambda)(\lambda^2 -\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)) = (-1-\lambda)(\lambda^2-1).$$ Thus, as I said above, the eigenvalues are $-1,-1$ and $1$.

Comment: Indeed, WolframAlpha agrees with me: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=characteristic+polynomial+of++{{-1,0,0},{0,-cos%28x%29,sin%28x%29},{0,sin%28x%29,cos%28x%29}}

Comment: Yes you right! I did it another time and I did a sign error. I delete my answer! ;)